# MacOS, iTerms 2 copy is control c not command c, how to change the shortcut?

Tags: zsh

[now shortcut screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n7lRu.jpg)

I don't know what cause the situation. I search in the Preference but find nothing.

Comment: It is normal in other softwares

Comment: What version of iTerm2 are you using? I'm using the latest beta copy (3.5.0beta5) and don't see the control key replacing the command key for shortcuts.

Comment: I am using iTerm2. I think it is not the version problem. I try to uninstall the iTerms2 and install the latest stable version 3.4.15. @chepner . Or I can ask in another way: how the iTerms 2 define the COPY is command + C? what file or ENVIRONMENT VARIABLE it read?

Comment: I don't know, because I don't know how you got in this state in the first place. It seems strange that you even *can* get into this state.